# Content Color of CSS doesn't work on Firefox Printer when we press Ctrl+P

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing, font-awesome

In Firefox, when I press Ctrl+p to print content `Thumb` icon in `Red Color`, `Thumb` icon printed out in `Black Color`, could you please help me out?

```css
@media print {
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#wrap:after {
  content: "\f087";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ff2d00;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Hi Bo SENG, please add some printscreen

Comment: Can you first try: on your right top menu > click Print to see the preview before?
https://support.mozilla.org/km/kb/how-print-web-pages-firefox

Comment: I removed your margin, left and top from the css so the icon is visible in the snippet and it doesn't seem to affect your question. If this is incorrect you can undo my change.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have color printing to test but base on spec. can you try to change to this

`@media print {
  * {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    printer-colors: exact !important;
    color-adjust: exact !important;
   }
}`

Reference: https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/print-backgrounds

Supported: Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, I find its solution, in fact we need to configure in "Page Setup" of Firefox is just Tick "Print background (colors & images)" event if we don't set these codes.

```
@media print {
    * {
       -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        printer-colors: exact !important;
        color-adjust: exact !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should mark !important to each css value.
Ex: color: #ff2d00 !important;
Because we worry about other style already define it as bootstrap.